# When setting up app.yaml url handler, how to format url to script?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, cron, wsgi

I'm not sure how to set up the url to a script for handler within app.yaml. I've tried following the docs (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) on setting up a cron job, but my crons are failing in GAE. I am also getting this error: 
`\myproject\app.yaml: threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: myprojectApp/dsProcess.aggregate`

I think the docs assume that I am not using WSGI, but my use of WSGI is somehow affecting how scripts are accessed within the application.

This is my project structure with the pertinent files:

```
myproject/
    myproject/      (package for project)
        urls.py     (defers url handling to myprojectApp.urls)
    myprojectApp/   (package for actual app)
        urls.py
        dsProcess.py  ( contains the aggregate function my cron should call)
    app.yaml
    cron.yaml
    main.py
```

Within app.yaml, I'm not sure how to format the url to dsProcess.py's aggregate function:

**app.yaml**

```
handlers:
- url: /aggDB
  script: myprojectApp/dsProcess.aggregate <-- unsure here
```

should it be myprojectApp.dsProcess.aggregate instead?
`myprojectApp.dsProcess.aggregate.py`? `myprojectApp.dsProcess.aggregate.app`?

I'm running Python 2.7.9

**cron.yaml**

```
cron:
- description: aggregates db
  url: /aggDB
  schedule: every 1 mins
```

**main.py**

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi    
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**myprojectApp/dsProcess.py**

```
def aggregate():
```

**myproject/urls.py** and **myprojectApp/urls.py**

I'm guessing I don't need to set up url patterns within these for the `aggDB/` url that will be hit, since `app.yaml`  will register and listen for that url pattern for me. Is this correct?

Nonetheless, here are the two urls.py:

*myproject/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       (r'^', include('myprojectApp.urls')),
                       )
```

*myprojectApp/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
     #don't need to handle this here, let app.yaml handle it?  
    # (r'^aggDB/$', dsProcess.aggDStoJSON()),
)
```

Would me use of wsgi affect how I access my scripts? If so, how and why?

Answer (score 1):

It's a Python path, you use dots not slashes.

But there is nothing special about the cron URLs: they are exactly the same as any other URLs in your project, and follow exactly the same rules. If you want it to be handled by Django, you don't need to add a specific entry in the app.yaml at all, just let it use the existing mapping for the rest of the Django URLs.